# How is OAUTH2 user id generated?

Tags: mysql, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I've been learning to use Facebook and Google login using Passport.js, here's how a typical user object that they provide:

```
{
    id: "1234567",
    displayName: "John Smith",
    name: {
        familyName: "Smith",
        givenName: "John"
    }

    // emails, photos, etc.
}
```

Now, I'm trying to know how the `id` field is generated and how come they are unique across different login providers. It doesn't seem to be a UUID.

The users are saved into a MySQL database with their `id`'s as primary key; and I'm trying to implement a regular username/password login so I need to generate `id`'s of my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook and Google IDs stopped being interesting years ago. You should NOT use that ID as a "real" OR UUID identifier.

Yes you are right, you have to generate your own ids and also save the other "external" ids if you want to have SSO. For your own ids, I recommend you a simple mysql autoincrement id for PK. [Take care of this is you need to scale it](https://tomharrisonjr.com/uuid-or-guid-as-primary-keys-be-careful-7b2aa3dcb439).

If you have to expose your own id, you need to have your own "external" id, [also take care of the security requirements of this](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10631806).

Finally, [OAuth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) does not state anything regarding the format of a user ID.

Best!